# Extract number from an URL regex java

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract an last number from an URL followed by a dash.

Example:

http://www.example.com/p-test-test1-a-12345.html

i need to extract the 12345 using regex.

i tried this `-\d(.*?).html` which gives me `2345` not sure why it removes 1 any idea?

Comment: What do you think `\d` would match?

Comment: Which technique are you using : grouping or Pattern and Matcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It removes the first digit as you have invalid pattern it captures everything after `-digit`

`-\d(.*?).html`

`-\d` - **matches** a dash followed by a digit

`(.*?)` - **captures** any character (except new line) 0 or more times till next token is satisifed

`.` - **matches** any character (except new line)

`html` - **matches** `html`

---

Try this pattern:

**PATTERN**

```
(?<=-)\d+(?=\.html)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add `\d` to group: `-(\d.*?).html`

if it must be only digits then `-(\d+)\.html` is better.

Comment: it will match any numer followed by `!html` as well

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a dash, then a digit, then capturing all characters before ".html", which is why the 1 was not captured.

Try this instead:

`-(\d+)\.html`

Comment: There're no needs to make the `+` ungreedy.

Comment: @M42 You're quite right. I suppose that's what happens when I edit existing code without thinking it through properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
String pattern2 = ".*?(\\d+)\\.html";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pattern2, "$1"));
```